# Java - FileDialog Questions/Assistance

Tags: java, swing, load, awt, directory

I am sure these are very nooby questions... But I have never had to deal with FileDialog before and I can't seem to get my coding to work.

This is my listener for my JButton, which I know it enters because a FileDialog pops up:

```
public static class FileListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Pick Folder");
        String dir = "C:/";
        fd.setDirectory(dir);
        fd.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        fd.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        String pickedFileDir = fd.getFile();
        File folder = new File(pickedFileDir);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        numOfFiles = listOfFiles.length;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want it to be able to load a FOLDER. I need to get a directory out of it. And even when I do click on 1 file and press "Open" the numOfFiles doesn't change. I know this because of this code:

```
JLabel number = new JLabel("Files found: " + numOfFiles);
```

The label doesn't change after opening a file. It should go from "0" to "1".

Much appreciated if you can help me figure this out (obviously a "Best Answer" in there for ya :) )

Comment: Take a look at JFileChooser - it will make your life easier.  You'll find the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JFileChooser instead. Here is your example:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/"));
if (jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    File[] listOfFiles = selectedFile.listFiles();
}
```

Comment: Wow. That looks so much easier. Thanks (Last time I did anything with Files was like 2 years ago... I never even heard of JFileChooser back then)
It works. BUT the number things doesn't change. Do I have to update the JLabel somehow?

Comment: -1, Paul gave a link to the Swing tutorial that shows how to use the JFileChooser 20 minutes before this was posted. Therefore this question was answered in the comment and a duplicate answer was not required. A link to the tutorial is preferred because it a) answers the question b) gives the poster access to another reference that can be helpful in the future.

Comment: *"Last time I did anything with Files was like 2 years ago... I never even heard of JFileChooser back then"*  You need to crawl out from beneath whatever rock you have been living.  `JFileChooser` has been part of Swing since it's inception.  Swing was introduced into the J2SE in [Java 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_1.2#J2SE_1.2_.28December_8.2C_1998.29) which was released in 1998!  If you were working with files in 2009 that leaves 'only' 11 years for the wonders of Swing to (fail to) filter through to you.

Comment: Wow. I must have been living under a rock. Btw I never worked with Files extensively.